# No SDK on Intellij IDEA with jdk17 Installed

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sdk, java-17

When I try to create my first IDEA project, it shows [No SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQ3PR.png),
but JDK 17 is already installed on my system
[JDK in CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9VDu.png).

I'm new, and I would like to use IntelliJ IDEA with the JDK I have installed.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I don't use IDEA, but try setting `JAVA_HOME` and restarting

Answer (score 1):

By default, installed JDKs are not shown in IntelliJ IDEA from the get-go, you need to import them first. To import and select an installed JDK in IntelliJ IDEA, you need to go to your main menu and select `File > Project Structure`. Alternatively, you can use the shortcut `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + s` on Windows/Linux, while `⌘ + Alt + Shift + s` on macOS.

Once the Project Structure popup appears, select `project` on the left column, open the drop-down menu SDK and click on `Add JDK...`.

[image]

At this point, browse to your JDK installation folder, select it and click on `Ok`.

[image]

Now you can select your installed JDK from the dropdown menu. Click on `Apply` and then `OK` to confirm your choice.

See:

- [*Project structure settings*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-settings-and-structure.html) by JetBrains
- [*SDKs*](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sdk.html) by JetBrains
- [*How to Change the Java Version in an IntelliJ Project*](https://www.baeldung.com/intellij-change-java-version) at Baeldung.com

Comment: Thanks @Basil Bourque for the links provided

Answer (score -1):

You can add java SDK through project structure under IntelliJ IDEA settings. If you don't know how to add SDK. plz follow below instructions.

1. Open IntelliJ IDEA and go to the Welcome Screen or open an existing project.
2. Go to File > Project Structure (or use the shortcut `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S` on Windows/Linux or `Cmd+;` on macOS).
3. In the Project Structure window, select the SDK (Software Development Kit) option from the left-hand side menu.
4. If you have an installed JDK on your system, you should see it listed under the "JDK home path" section. If not, click on the **"+"** (Plus) icon at the top to add a new JDK.
5. In the "Add New SDK" dialog box, select the option "Download JDK" or "Download JDK from..." if you don't have a JDK installed on your system.
6. Choose the desired Java version from the list and click "Download". IntelliJ IDEA will download and configure the Java SDK for you.
7. If you already have a JDK installed on your system, click the "..." (Ellipsis) button next to the JDK home path field and navigate to the directory where the JDK is installed.
8. Select the JDK directory and click "OK" to apply the changes.
9. Click "OK" to close the Project Structure window.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).